# 2nd value in javascript array always unidentified

Tags: javascript

Got this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imones = [];
imones.push('example.com');
imones.push('cnn.com');
imones.push('apple.com');


var beforeloadingtime = (new Date()).getTime();
var beforeTime = [];
beforeTime[0] = beforeloadingtime;
$.each(imones, function (index, value) {
    var jsonnuorodos = "http://anyorigin.com/get?url=" + imones[index] + "&callback=?";
    $.getJSON(jsonnuorodos, function (data) {
        var iframe = $("#output")[0];
        var doc = iframe.document;
        if (iframe.contentDocument) {
            doc = iframe.contentDocument;
        } else if (iframe.contentWindow) {
            doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        }
        doc.open();
        doc.writeln(data.contents);
        doc.close();
        var loadingtime = (new Date()).getTime();
        beforeTime.push(loadingtime);

        var result;
        result = (beforeTime[index + 1] - beforeTime[index]) / 1000;
        console.log("result - " + result);
    });
});
</script>
```

In console i get these results:

```
result - 1.741 
result - NaN 
result - 0.86
```

I am getting NaN on my 2nd result because beforeTime[index+1] value is always unidentified.

Edit:
if i write `console.log("index= "+[index]); console.log("index+1= "+[index+1]);` i am getting:

```
index= 0 
index+1= 1 
index= 2
index+1= 3
index= 1
index+1= 2
```

where it should have been:

```
index= 0 
index+1= 1 
index= 1
index+1= 2
index= 2
index+1= 3
```

Comment: you should consider following the rules of this community and format your javascript so it becomes readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding a simple for loop:

```
for (i=0;i<4;i++){
var result;
result = (beforeTime[i+1] - beforeTime[i]) / 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe the reason is that you use the `$.getJson` and you use `$.each`to create this function. That is nonsynchronous. The `index=3` 's response speed faster than `index=2`, so....